# Can SQL Server sysadmin create a rule in a DB that prevents users from executing certain types of queries?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am the sysadmin on a small SQL Server. Can I store rules in the Databases that prevent certain types of SQL statements to be run? Example would be when a user tries to execute `SELECT * FROM ...` Can I "ban" these types of solutions? Other examples I would like to ban would be create ##Temp Tables in memory, or even creating a table / querying a table without a Primary Key.

It would be great if I could display a message saying why this statement isn't allowed with a message of my choosing.

Comment: do you want to restrict all users? or specific users (not sysadmin)? In database properties Restrict Access = Restricted_User means that database can be accessed by users with sysadmin and dbcreator server roles and db_owner database role. I believe there is no way to prevent Temp table creation. It's takes place in the tempDB space it won't effect anything.

Comment: Going out on a limb here but I suspect if you did manage to ban such things you would absolutely cripple the database. You would probably even find that all sorts of system operations stopped working. Better to monitor usage through the profiler and work with anyone who is performing operations you don't approve of that actually matter.

Comment: Short answer - no. And Off-topic for SO - more appropriate for [dba](https://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @SMor - thank you, was looking for that area but had trouble finding.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if understood question correctly, but:

```
REVOKE SELECT ON database TO 'user'@'localhost';
```